# Can I calculate a field directly in an Extjs grid?

Tags: extjs, tabular

Example table:

```
|-Field quantity-|-Field quantity loss-|----Total------|
|-----2----------|-------4-------------|---total=2+4---|
|-----3----------|-------5-------------|---total=3+5---|
```

Can I render it by function on extjs?

total=field quantity + Field quantity Loss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you must use the grid getColumnModel method.

```
  grid.getColumnModel().setRenderer(2, function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
      return record.get('quantity') + record.get('loss');
    });
```

More info: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/?class=Ext.grid.GridPanel and
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/?class=Ext.grid.ColumnModel?class=Ext.grid.ColumnModel